# Number of Binary Strings of Length $n$ with Hamming Distance $n/2$

Tags: combinatorics

Consider an [Hadamard matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) of order $n$, which is a multiple of 4:

- each element is either $1$ or $-1$,
- every pair of distinct rows have [hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) $n/2$; that is, two distinct $n$ bit strings (which correspond to rows of an Hadamard matrix) differ in exactly $n/2$ positions.

My question is: What can we say about the number of possible candidate rows in an Hadamard matrix of order $n$? Put another way,
$$\text{What is the largest number of $n$ bit strings whose hamming distance is $n/2$?}$$

Comment: I think there's a general theorem that the number of subsets of an $n$-set, each pair having exactly $k$ elements in common, is never more than $n$. In fact, I think I saw that very theorem stated here (or maybe on MathOverflow) very recently (in the last day or two).

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I think this is (at least related to) the Frankl-Wilson theorem. Having difficulty tracking it down exactly.

Comment: @Ben, I think you're right. Type Frankl-Wilson site:math.stackexchange.com (or, Frankl-Wilson site:mathoverflow.net) into Google to see what comes up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formulation in terms of Hamming distance seems to be a good one for making progress.

The quantity you want then seems to be denoted $A_2(n,n/2)$.  The [Plotkin bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plotkin_bound) gives: if $n/2$ is even then $A_2(n,n/2) \le 2n$, otherwise $A_2(n,n/2) \le 2\lfloor n/2+1 \rfloor = n+1$.

A lower bound can be found by constructing an explicit set.  For the special case $n=2^t$ for positive integer $t$, consider the strings $0^n, 0^{n/2}1^{n/2}, 0^{n/4}1^{n/4}0^{n/4}1^{n/4},\dots, 0^21^20^2\dots 0^21^2, 0101\dots 01$. This satisfies the conditions and has $t+1 = 1 + \log_2 n$ strings.

I suspect that better bounds are known, and would be interested in a more precise analysis.  Perhaps someone like [Peter Cameron](http://cameroncounts.wordpress.com/) might be able to provide pointers.

---

It is worth remarking that there is an interesting reformulation of your problem in terms of set systems.

Given a set of strings which are all distance $n/2$ from each other, first transform the coordinate system.  Pick one string in the set and flip its 1 bits to make it the all-zero string.  Applying the same permutation to each of the other strings retains the Hamming distances.
This leads to every string other than $0^n$ having exactly $n/2$ bits set to 1.

Consider the set system of which these strings are the characteristic vectors of sets in the system, *excluding* the all-zero vector.  Each set contains precisely $n/2$ elements.  Observe that the pairwise intersections contain precisely $n/4$ elements.

Then your question can be rephrased as follows (equivalent up to the difference of 1 from excluding the $0^n$ string).

> What is the largest possible set system of subsets of an $n$-element set, such that each contains precisely $n/2$ elements, and such that their pairwise intersections have precisely $n/4$ elements?

Again this sounds natural and I would expect this is known, but I did not find anything about this problem in the Lovász *Combinatorial Problems and Exercises* book or in the Deza/Frankl survey from 1983; it seems a bit tricky to find the right online search terms.  The usual setup for [Erdős–Ko–Rado](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Ko%E2%80%93Rado_theorem) style results is more relaxed, allowing intersections of at least some threshold; here all pairwise intersections are precisely $n/4$.

- M. Deza and P. Frankl, *Erdös–Ko–Rado Theorem—22 Years Later*, SIAM J. Alg. Disc. Meth. **4** 419–431, 1983. doi:[10.1137/0604042](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0604042)

There is another potentially relevant paper but I have not been able to extract much from it (or at least from the scanned image of the paper).

- R. Ahlswede and G. O. H. Katona, *Contributions to the geometry of Hamming spaces*, DM **17** 1–22, 1977.  doi:[10.1016/0012-365X(77)90017-6](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X%2877%2990017-6)

Comment: I think the question in your blockquote is what Frankl-Wilson can be applied to – you get an upper bound of $n$ sets in your system, essentially by orthogonality. This is stronger than the Plotkin bound for the same reason that it's stronger than the EKR approach, I think.

Comment: @BenMillwood: Thanks, Frankl-Wilson does indeed give an upper bound of $n+1$ strings (or $n$ sets).  It is not immediately obvious that its proof via containment matrices yields a better lower bound, though.

Comment: See also my follow-on question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/135509/better-bounds-for-exact-intersection-erdoskorado-system which led to the essentially optimal bounds, via results of Ryser and Sylvester.